# imagemagick identify gives "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib"

Tags: imagemagick, osx-mountain-lion, ghostscript

after brew install imagemagick and brew install ghostscript on osx
when i run identify i get:

```
$ identify
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 17):

this fixes it

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/3.9.5/lib/libtiff.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib
```

thanks to rlaraujo on this link https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12099

Comment: Had a similar issue. Creating a symlink fixed this for me. But had to locate libtiff file from /opt/local/lib:

`sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib`

Comment: This also works when trying to get the tesseract gem running correctly in ruby.

Answer (score 11):

For me the error was:

```
$ php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_4/lib/libgd.3.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

For me the fix was `brew upgrade gd`

Comment: That fixed it, thank you man. I started getting this error after brew install composer and this fixed it!

Comment: this one fixed for me, too. I had the same issue after installing composer with home-brew

Comment: You are a life savor ++

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem recently on 10.6.8.  I had ImageMagick installed (from way back) and then installed `freetype` and `ghostscript` and started getting the failure.  The fix for me was simply to upgrade ImageMagick, which rebuilt and linked up to the newer `libtiff` and other libraries.

```
brew upgrade imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with `libpng` library when I tried to use `convert`command with png files.

I first tried upgrading imagemagick but there were no upgrades available for the current version of brew I had. Updating brew and then upgrading ImageMagick solved the problem.

```
brew update
brew upgrade imagemagick
```